# SQL Query to find total count in certain price range

Tags: sql

Need your help with a SQL Query and how should I write it? 
I have a table with total_value and order_id and would like to find the number of orders whose total value is in the range of 0-50, 51-100, over 100

Thank you !

Comment: I think that you should go through an SQL tutorial. More than a programming problem I see a lack of self study.

Comment: Great and thanks, and any good SQL tutorial would you able to recommend ? I read couple and none of them help out with this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want a case statement.

something like:

```
select count(order_id),
       value_range
from 
     (select order_id,
            total_value,
            case when total_value between 0 and 50 then '0-50'
                when total_value between 51 and 100 then '51-100'
                when total_value > 100 then '100'
            end as value_range
       from table)a
group by value_range
```

Comment: will this really work in SQL: `between 0-50`. Shouldnt it be `between 0 and 50`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
select count(order_id),
       valueRange
from 
     (select order_id,
            total_value,
            case when total_value between 0 and 50 then '0-50'
                when total_value between 51 and 100 then '51-100'
                when total_value > 100 then '100'
            end as valueRange
       from table)a
 Group by valueRange
```

Comment: Thank you logixologist and CEvans! ! is there an another way that I don't have to use case and when ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Conditional SUM:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Value BETWEEN 0 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Range1
    ,  SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Value BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Range2
    ,  SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Value > 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Range3
FROM your_table
```